# Django Form - include a "reset" button

Tags: django, forms, filter

I've managed to include a form in my django project using FilterSet. It works very well - no issues. 
When I have typed something in the form to make a search ('for instance BMW'), the table in my template is filtered on ('BMW'), though my search 'BMW' stays in the field. Hence, I would like to include a button 'clear' on which the user can click and 'BMW' disappears from the field & the search result goes back to the initial table. How can I realise this?

Currently I have included a button in my template (but nothing happens when I click on it)

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="resetEffort()"">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Clear
</button>
```

And this is my view.py:

```
def cars_overview(request):
 car = CarFilter(request.GET, queryset=Car.objects.all())
 return render(request, 'cars/cars.html', {'filter': car})
```

many thanks !

Comment: You could use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the event, pause it, clear the values, and then submit the form using js.

```
document.querySelector('button[type="reset"]').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  this.parentElement.reset();
  this.parentElement.submit();
})
```